# PARTITION BY first use of a particular product

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partitioning

I'm trying to produce a table that lists the month, account and product name from our billing database. However, I also want to understand (for subsequent cohort analysis) what the earliest use is of "Product A" for each line item too. I was hoping I could do the following:

```
SELECT 
  Month,
  AccountID,
  ProductName,
  SUM(NetRevenue) AS NetRevenue,
  MIN(Month) OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID, 'Product A') AS EarliestUse 
FROM
  <<my-billing-table>>
WHERE
  NetRevenue > 0
  AND AccountID IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT AccountID
      FROM <<my-billing-table>>
      WHERE ProductName = 'Product A' AND NetRevenue > 0
    )
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

...but it seems that just using "Product A" within the `OVER` clause does not have the desired effect (it seems to just return the first month for AccountID).

While the syntax is fine and the query runs, I'm obviously missing something regarding `PARTITION`ing the `OVER` clause. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation along with a window function:

```
SELECT Month, AccountID, ProductName,
       SUM(NetRevenue) AS NetRevenue,
       MIN(MIN(CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Product A' THEN month END)) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID) AS EarliestUse 
FROM <<my-billing-table>>
WHERE NetRevenue > 0 AND
      AccountID IN (SELECT AccountID
                    FROM <<my-billing-table>>
                    WHERE ProductName = 'Product A' AND NetRevenue > 0
                   )
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

The key expression here is an aggregation function nestled inside a window function.  The aggregation function is `MIN(CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Product A' THEN month END)`.  This calculates the earliest month for the specified product on each row.  This could be a column in the result set, and you would see the minimum value on the product row.

The window function then "spreads" this value over all rows for a given `AccountID`.

Comment: Yes! I think this works, thank you. Would you mind quickly explaining the double `MIN`?

Answer (score 0):

you are using a constant in partition it will not impact in your result, should use the column ProductName in partition to get the earliest use of the product

```
SELECT 
  Month,
  AccountID,
  ProductName,
  SUM(NetRevenue) AS NetRevenue,
  MIN(Month) OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID, ProductName) AS EarliestUse
FROM
  <<my-billing-table>>
WHERE
  NetRevenue > 0
  AND AccountID IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT AccountID
      FROM <<my-billing-table>>
      WHERE ProductName = 'Product A' AND NetRevenue > 0
    )
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, as it'll produce the earliest use date of the ProductName per line item (i.e., for Product B, it'll show the earliest use of Product B, not Product A).